# MATLAB reset axes position copied from GUIDE

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

After copying an axes from `GUIDE` to a new figure,

```
f=figure;
copyobj(handles.axes1,f)
```

I found out that the position of axes1 is not on the right place. How can I reset new axes position to the default value? This value it copied from the position in `GUIDE` which should not be in that place in figure.

[image: figure axes position]

Comment: Have you tried to set the axis `'Position'` property?

Comment: @patrik `Position` depends on pixel size which is variable between my monitors size and window size. I prefer avoid magic numbers. I want to get those numbers automatically according to what is required.

Comment: What do you mean with magic numbers? You can set the `Units` property to normalized to get them normalized relative to the figure window. This should work for any screen and window size.

Comment: @patrik What should I set for `units`?

Comment: Set the property `Units` for the axes to normalized, `set(axes_handle, 'Units', ''normalized');`. Then you make the position independent of the screen resolution.

Comment: @zahmati - please add the solution that worked for you as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is using `normalized` units:

```
set(gca,'Units','normalized','Position',[0.1 0.1 0.8 0.8])
```